# CompletableFuture.allOf() not completing after individual futures

Tags: java, completable-future

When I use CompletableFuture.allOf() to combine independent completable futures as described in the javadoc it does not reliably complete after all futures supplied to the method.
E.g.:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class CompletableFutureTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Runnable dummyTask = () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        };

        CompletableFuture<Void> f1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(dummyTask);
        CompletableFuture<Void> f2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(dummyTask);
        CompletableFuture[] all = {f1, f2};
        f1.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> System.out.println("Completed f1"));
        f2.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> System.out.println("Completed f2"));
        CompletableFuture<Void> allOf = CompletableFuture.allOf(all);
        allOf.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> {
                    System.out.println("Completed allOf");
                }
        );
        allOf.join();
        System.out.println("Joined");
    }
}
```

Leads to the following result:

```
Completed f2
Joined
Completed allOf
Completed f1
```

I would expect the logging "Joined" and "Completed allOf" to be written after "Completed f1" and "Completed f2". 
To make things more confusing the order of the futures in the array seems top matter. If I changed the line

```
CompletableFuture[] all = {f1, f2};
```

to

```
CompletableFuture[] all = {f2, f1};
```

The resulting output changes to:

```
Completed allOf
Completed f1
Completed f2
Joined
```

And to make things even worse, if I run the exact same code several times, the order changes again. I could understand that the order of "f1" and "f2" change randomly, and likewise for "allOf" and "Joined". But this is really surprising.

In case it matters: This is JDK 1.8.0_91 on Windows 7.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade your Java version first, the latest Java 8 is update 152. Who knows, this might be a bug that was fixed.

Comment: join() is not the same as Thread.join;  it doesn’t wait for completion.  Use [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--) instead.

Comment: @VGR a `CompleteFuture.join()` does wait (check its Java doc and implementation).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel “Returns the result value when complete, or throws an (unchecked) exception if completed exceptionally. To better conform with the use of common functional forms, if a computation involved in the completion of this CompletableFuture threw an exception, this method throws an (unchecked) `CompletionException` with the underlying exception as its cause.”  I see no mention of waiting.  Also, the method cannot throw InterruptedException, which is a strong hint that it will not wait.

Comment: After further reading, I stand corrected;  join() does wait for completion.

Comment: @VGR I agree that the javadoc is slightly ambiguous

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f1.whenComplete` returns a new future that is independent from `f1`. `AllOf` will wait for `f1` to complete, but not wait for the lambda passed to `whenComplete` to complete. To get the result you're after, you can try something like:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class CompletableFutureTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Runnable dummyTask = () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        };

        CompletableFuture<Void> f1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(dummyTask);
        CompletableFuture<Void> f2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(dummyTask);
        f1 = f1.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> System.out.println("Completed f1"));
        f2 = f2.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> System.out.println("Completed f2"));
        CompletableFuture[] all = {f1, f2};
        CompletableFuture<Void> allOf = CompletableFuture.allOf(all);
        allOf.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> {
            System.out.println("Completed allOf");
        });
        allOf.join();
        System.out.println("Joined");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is OK - No one guaranteed the order of callbacks.

Comment: I did not -1 this, but how about the javadoc saying "a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete"

Comment: ok, in retrospect your comment makes sense. A bit of elaboration would have helped :-)

Comment: You didn't asked to help you to print the messages in order, you asked to explain the behavior 

Answer (score -1):

Call join on the wenComplete method

```
allOf.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> {
                System.out.println("Completed allOf");
            }
    ).join();
```